# Background image not showing. Js

Tags: javascript

Very new to coding so forgive my ignorance but I am having a problem with a background image showing up. I am using Javascript and sublime text. I added the image and the entire folder with other images id like to add to the site later on and seem to get an error where the image isn't found.
Thanks for any help
first image is code in sublime text
second image is console and google chrome view

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcPz8.png),
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fiovx.png)

Comment: Please use code instead of text (using `\`\`\``) to help screen-readers. Read more in the Stack Overflow help page.

Comment: Your  p element has not width and height.I think you should  try to add some text in to it or give width and height by using css.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your p element has no width and height since it is empty. You can try to add some text in to it or give width/height by manually. Also you have to close p tag like below .

```
<p style="background-image: url('new-world-03.jpg');width:200px;height:200px;">
  Lorem ipsum
</p>
```